# Relation between measurable sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Given an outer measure $\mu^*$ with domain $X$ and a subset $B$ of $X$, one can construct a new outer measure $\nu^*(A) = \mu^*(A \cap B)$. The problem is to find the relation between the measurable sets with regard to each outer measure.

First; suppose $E$ is a $\mu^*$-measurable set. Then the inequality $\mu^*(A) \geq \mu^*(A\cap E) + \mu^*(A - E)$ hold for all sets $A \subset X$ (note; $A - E = A \cap E^c$.) In particular it holds for $A\cap B$, and thus we have that $\nu^*(A) \geq \nu^*(A \cap E) + \nu^*(A - E)$ hold for all $A$. That is, if $E$ is $\mu^*$-measurable then it is also $\nu^*$-measurable (just replace $A$ with $A \cap B$, and use $(A\cap B) - E = (A - E) \cap B$)

However, I find it difficult going the other way around? Say that $E$ is $\nu^*$-measurable. Then $\nu^*(A) \geq \nu^*(A \cap E) + \nu^*(A - E)$ for all $A \subset X$. But now I am stuck. Translating this to $\mu^*$ we have that $\mu^*(A\cap B) \geq \mu^*((A\cap B) \cap E) + \mu^*((A\cap B) - E)$. One could argue that, since $\mu^*(A) \geq \mu^*(A\cap B)$, sets like $E \supset B$ will satisfy the inequality for all $A$. However this seems like taking it to the extreme?

If anyone could point out the (probably obvious) thing I am missing it would be much appreciated!

Comment: "Find the relation between measurable sets with regard to each outer measure" is vague to me. Is there any context to this question? Would you like a result of the form, "there exists a family $\mathcal{A}$ of sets $A \subset X$ such that if $E$ is $\nu_A^*$ measurable for all $A \in \mathcal{A}$, then $E$ is $\mu^*$-measurable"? (Here, $\nu_A^* := \mu^*(\cdot \cap A)$.

Comment: Thanks for commenting, and I agree it is somewhat vague. The question is from Friedman's Modern Analysis (it's question 1.3.4) and, after one has proved that $\nu^*$ is an outer measure one is asked to "find the relation between the measurable sets of $\mu^*$ and $\nu^*$". From this, I supposed that the relation would be "clear" in some sense.